# Setting a highlight on text removes mouse highlight on that text

Tags: java, swing

I am highlighting some text in a text area:

```
Highlighter highlighter = getHighlighter();
Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(new Color(201, 197, 198));
highlighter.addHighlight(0,10, painter);
```

This works fine. However I would like the default highlight colour to be used when I highlight the text using my mouse. When the mouse no longer highlights the text, it will revert back to my chosen highlight colour, `new Color(201, 197, 198);`

It is possible for the mouse highlight to take priority over my set highlight?

Thanks

Comment: You mean you don't want to apply the highlighter to selected text?

Comment: I still want to apply the highlighter whenever you use the mouse. I want to keep the highlight I set but when I use the mouse to highlight that selected text I want the mouse highlight to take effect (i.e the text highlight changes to a blueish color). When the mouse is no longer highlighting that text it resorts back to my highlight I set on it

Comment: Can you elaborbate a bit more? How do you use the mouse to highlight the text - by hovering the mouse over some text or the selected text? Could you provide a small screenshot that shows what you want to achieve?

Comment: this selection should be (f.e. red) for whole JTextArea, red for plain text and with same red for highlighted text

Comment: [SystemColor.textHighlight](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SystemColor.html#textHighlight) is a good choice, as it typically reflects a system default or the user's control panel choice.

Comment: @Thomas I use the mouse to highlight the normal way. Pressing and dragging. I have some text highlighted when the textarea is created. This is a grey color. When I click and drag the mouse over the grey highlighted text the text remains grey but I want to be the system color highlight.

Comment: I want the color I set to be different from the System Color.

Comment: @Decrypter what you're describing is a selection. Initially no text is selected but some parts are highlighted. When you drag the mouse you select some text in the component which will then be highlighted using the system color. In that case try to adjust the highlighted area to exclude the selected text when the highlight is drawn (you have access to the text component and thus should be able to get the selected text as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own Highlighter and set to the JTextComponent. See DefaultHighlighter.

The order of paints is defined in the method below but highlights and LayeredHighlightInfo aren't accessible to override (package level)

```
public void paintLayeredHighlights(Graphics g, int p0, int p1,
                       Shape viewBounds,
                       JTextComponent editor, View view) {
    for (int counter = highlights.size() - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
        Object tag = highlights.elementAt(counter);
        if (tag instanceof LayeredHighlightInfo) {
        LayeredHighlightInfo lhi = (LayeredHighlightInfo)tag;
        int start = lhi.getStartOffset();
        int end = lhi.getEndOffset();
        if ((p0 < start && p1 > start) ||
            (p0 >= start && p0 < end)) {
            lhi.paintLayeredHighlights(g, p0, p1, viewBounds,
                           editor, view);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for lesson about Attibute, nice code +1, maybe there I miss something, but let's leave that, not rellated with OP's question

Comment: so ehm... where should we get 'highlights' and 'LayeredHighlightInfo' ?

Answer (score 1):

maybe (Stas and Rob) implemented own Highlighter where is required to overrive Rectangle/Shape from API against Mouse_selection

but more confortable would be use JTextPane with AttributeSet, but miss there Highlighter with colored Rectangle

for example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ColorPane extends JTextPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void appendNaive(Color c, String s) { // naive implementation
        // bad: instiantiates a new AttributeSet object on each call
        SimpleAttributeSet aset = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setForeground(aset, c);
        int len = getText().length();
        setCaretPosition(len); // place caret at the end (with no selection)
        setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        replaceSelection(s); // there is no selection, so inserts at caret
    }

    public void append(Color c, String s) { // better implementation--uses       
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext(); // StyleContext
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY,
                StyleConstants.Foreground, c);
        int len = getDocument().getLength(); // same value as
        //getText().length();
        setCaretPosition(len); // place caret at the end (with no selection)
        setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        replaceSelection(s); // there is no selection, so inserts at caret
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        UIManager.put("TextPane.selectionBackground", Color.yellow);
        UIManager.put("TextPane.selectionForeground", Color.blue);
        ColorPane pane = new ColorPane();
        for (int n = 1; n <= 400; n += 1) {
            if (isPrime(n)) {
                pane.append(Color.red, String.valueOf(n) + ' ');
            } else if (isPerfectSquare(n)) {
                pane.append(Color.blue, String.valueOf(n) + ' ');
            } else {
                pane.append(Color.black, String.valueOf(n) + ' ');
            }
        }
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ColorPane example");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(pane));
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        double max = Math.sqrt(n);
        for (int j = 2; j <= max; j += 1) {
            if (n % j == 0) {
                return false; // j is a factor
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isPerfectSquare(int n) {
        int j = 1;
        while (j * j < n && j * j > 0) {
            j += 1;
        }
        return (j * j == n);
    }
}
```

or convert this code from Caret to the Painter

```
class HighlightCaret extends DefaultCaret {

    private static final Highlighter.HighlightPainter unfocusedPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(new Color(230, 230, 210));
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean isFocused;

    @Override
    protected Highlighter.HighlightPainter getSelectionPainter() {
        return isFocused ? super.getSelectionPainter() : unfocusedPainter;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectionVisible(boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus != isFocused) {
            isFocused = hasFocus;
            super.setSelectionVisible(false);
            super.setSelectionVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding something to attributes mean Document (model) changes. It's slow if you would like to highlight e.g. spellcheck errors.